# Custom openapi documentation can't be applied for springdoc-openapi-ui web view

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to set up swagger-ui based on on existing json config, using `'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.9'` dependency (spring boot + gradle)

what I have is:

- custom
  `openapi.json` file in my 'resources/static' folder
- `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=openapi.json` in my properties

This should be enough according to [documentation](https://springdoc.org/#properties):

[image]

But I've faced a problem trying to open swagger-ui.html, it says "Fetch error
undefined openapi.json":
[image]
Looking at browser dev tools and requests, I found following request:

[image]

So it uses /swagger-ui/ in path and cannot reach resource.
My openapi.json available with simple http://localhost:8080/openapi.json, but w/o prefix.

I've tried to create "swagger-ui" dir under "static", but it did not help, file is still reachable in previous location.

I also tries to set`springdoc.api-docs.path`, but it did not help as well, it changes only generated api location.

Comment: Try `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/openapi.json` (note the slash `/` before the file name). Does this help?

Comment: Yes! It was the root cause (facepalm)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Helen mentioned, it was important to put / before the path
Changing property to `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/openapi.json` resolved issue!